# VK JS SDK возвращает пустой ответ при вызове метода

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, vk-mini-apps

Для создания приложения в вк использую Js Sdk. Авторизация проходит нормально.

```
connect.send("VKWebAppCallAPIMethod", {"method":"users.get", "request_id":"usersget", "params": {"user_ids":"0", "fields":"bdate,country,region,city", "v":"5.74", "access_token":token} });
```

А при вызове метода, ответ пустой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаёте **user_ids = 0,** поэтому ответ и пустой. Так и должно быть, исправьте на нужный вам id и данные будут

Comment: Для получения инфы о себе нужно использовать VKWebAppGetUserInfo. Привык что через user_ids=0 тоже можно.